# Ubuntu in virtual box not able to connect to internet

Tags: virtualbox, internet

Host- WindowsXP
Guest- Ubuntu 12.10

The host machine has internet connectivity, but I am not able to connect to internet in Ubuntu.
NAT-Using this I am able to ping a site, it shows packets sent and received but via browser I am not able to access.

Bridged- Not able to connect.

I have a static IP on my host machine and I use a proxy too.

Please let me know what is going wrong?